# VPN сервер, создание VPN подключения

Tags: python, vpn

Каким образом можно создать VPN сервер, к которому можно создать подключение через Питон?

Comment: Так вопрос в создании сервера или в подключении к серверу средствами python?

Comment: Скорее в подключении средствами

Comment: Запустить из питона программу или батник/скрипт, который в свою очередь запустит vpn-клиента, поднимет туннельные интерфейсы и т.д. и т.п. А если найдёте системные вызовы для этого и как вызывать их из питона, то будет ещё лучше.

Comment: если подключаемся средствами ОС, то какой ОС?

Comment: а так то щас как напишу впн сервер и клиента на питоне - тут на часик делов то

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через **http.server**:

````
import http.server
import urllib

PORT = 9097

class MyProxy(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        url=self.path[1:]
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(url), self.wfile)


httpd = socketserver.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), MyProxy)
print ("Now serving at", str(PORT))
httpd.serve_forever()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `requests`

```
import requests
proxies = {'http': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port',
           'https': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port'}

resp = requests.get('http://example.com', proxies=proxies )
```

Comment: Это решение для получения страницы из кода, я имел в виду создание постоянного подключения к vpn посредством ОС.

Comment: @JediKnight, а нафиг в этой схеме питон?